# Multiple docker containers, IP addresses, VM, OSX

Tags: linux, macos, docker, boot2docker

I am running docker on OSX via `boot2docker`. I am using docker remotely, via the API.

- I create several images of a web server. Docker assigns different IP address to each container, like `172.17.0.61`. Each web server is running on port 8080.
- Inside VM, I can ping the server on this address.

How can I map these different container IP addresses (from VM) to the same one in VM, but on different port? E.G.

```
<local.ip>:9001 -> 172.17.0.61:8080
<local.ip>:9002 -> 172.17.0.62:8080
```

where `local.ip` may be either ip from `boot2docker` or anything else.

Possible solution is to define *port bindings* when creating container and bind each container to a different port. However, I would like to avoid that, since this config becomes part of the container, and only exist because running on OSX. If I do all this above on linux, we would not have this issue.

How to map inner containers to different ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publishing ports is the right solution. You have the same problem whether you're running remotely or locally, just the IP address changes.

For example, say I start the following web servers:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8000:80 nginx
$ docker run -d -p 8001:80 nginx
```

From inside the VM (run `boot2docker ssh`), I can then run `curl localhost:8000` or `curl localhost:8001` to reach the website. This is the normal way of working with Docker on Linux. From the Mac command line, it becomes `curl $(boot2docker ip):8000` because of the VM, but we've not done anything different with regards to starting the web servers because of boot2docker.

Comment: so `curl $(bootdocker ip):8000` will reach only the first server, right? And to access the second one, I will need to open the port mapping in VM?

Comment: Can I run docker container on different IP addresses, but the same port?

Comment: If you have multiple IPs on the host, yes, just put the IP before the port: docker run -d -p 192.168.0.1:8000:80